# How to post a FragmentDialog immediately after another is dismissed and still maintain back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

So I'm using the fragment manager to show my dialogs as follows (this code is seen around a lot and seems to come from an example from google):

```
private void showDialogFragment(DialogFragment dialogFragment)
{
    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null)
    {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    dialogFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

The intention being to maintain a backstack of `DialogFragment`s if one is shown over another...

However, in one flow of this application we want to show one dialog before another. The user hits 'OK' to the first and the second presents OK/Cancel.

In my onClick handler for the first dialog I call dismiss to hide it, and then call a callback that then will fire another `DialogFragment` (it calls `showDialogFragment`. Like so (note that `dismiss` is documented to organise removing the fragment from the fragment manager):

```
.setPositiveButton(confirm,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                AlertDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
                if (listener != null)
                {
                    listener.doPositiveClick(requestIdentifier, extraArgs);
                }
            }
        }
)
```

The problem is that after I present the seconds, if i hit cancel, or back, it seems that the first was added to the back stack. In other words, in `showDialogFragment`, 'prev' is not null and is my first dialog. When prev is removed and added to the back stack like that, it seems to ignore the fact it has just been dismissed. Therefore when I hit 'Cancel' or BACK on the seconds dialog I return to the first! (it seems the dismiss was ignored). Interestingly, repeating the process once more seems to allow the first dialog to be properly dismissed.

Is there anything I could/should be checking about `prev` to see if it is in the process of being dismissed? (it still seems to show as attached, but is not in the view heirarchy)

I present one solution I have found to this problem in the answers below (use a delayed post of 0 time).

Answer (score 0):

One solution so this problem is to call the callbacks from the onClick handler with a delayed post of 0 time:

```
.setPositiveButton(confirm,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                AlertDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                //posting with a delay allows the dialog to remove itself before we post the next one
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if (listener != null)
                        {
                            listener.doPositiveClick(requestIdentifier, extraArgs);
                        }
                    }
                }, 0);

            }
        }
)
```

This seems to allow a run-loop to complete and have the dialog properly removed from the fragment manager. by the time `prev` is retrieved.